# get only one row and one column from table using nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I have query:

```
 var query = this.session.QueryOver<Products>()

.Where(uic => uic.PageNumber == nextPage[0])

.SingleOrDefault(uic => uic.ProductNumber)
```

But this query result is type Products. It is possible that result will be only integer type of column ProductNumber ?

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
var query = this.session.QueryOver<Products>()
    .Where(uic => uic.PageNumber == nextPage[0])
    .Select(uic => uic.ProductNumber)
    .SingleOrDefault<int>();
```

Since you need a single primitive type value, you can do `.Select` to define the result column, and then do `.SingleOrDefault` to get the only result. For complex types, you'd need to use transformers.

You can find more info about QueryOver in this blog post on nhibernate.info: http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.html

Comment: I think you want `SingleOrDefault` here and not `Single`.

Comment: Yes, `SingleOrDefault` should be used if "null result" is possible - 0 will be the default. If you always expect one item, then `Single` should be OK.

Comment: I don't think `Single` can even be called here though (i.e.: this won't compile). `SingleOrDefault` is a method on `IQueryOver<TRoot, TSubtype>`, while `Single` is not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Miroslav's answer for `QueryOver`, but this would look cleaner with LINQ:

```
var productNumber = session.Query<Products>()
                           .Where(uic => uic.PageNumber == nextPage[0])
                           .Select(uic => uic.ProductNumber)
                           .SingleOrDefault();
```

Notice you don't need a cast, as the `Select` operator changes the expression type to the return type of its parameter (which is the type of `ProductNumber`).

Comment: This LINQ query also will be invoke at db side?